# Stream large http response to disk in Erlang with httpc lib

Tags: erlang, streaming, erlang-otp, httpc

`httpc:request(get, {URL, []}, [], [{stream, FilePath}])` returns `{ok, saved_to_file}` even when the remote web-service dies midway while streaming the response. I checked the content on the disk was missing a whole bunch of data. Is this a known quirk and expected?

Comment: I'm using OTP-22.1. I have tried `{sync, false}` option as well but it made no difference.

Comment: You can use `cowboy_req`, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I filed a [bug-report](https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-1239) and the answer from OTP team indicated it was a bug (atleast for the current HTTP spec):

> I think this is due to that the client has backwards compatibility
>   with servers that would close the connection to indicate that all data
>   has been sent. Probably this should be made conditional for only old
>   versions of the HTTP protocol or maybe it could be dropped...
>   - Ingela Anderton Andin